# Spring Data JPA fails to return correct result with complex expression

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I try to implement filters for a some entity.
As far as I know, Spring doesn't support optional parameters so when no filter is set I check for *empty string* and when the parameter is set I want to match *contains* and *case insensitive*.

Currently, no Product is linked to a Role in the Database, so `p.role` is always null.
That means the second part of the expression (`lower(p.role.name) like concat('%', lower(:role), '%')`) is never true, resulting in an empty set.
But the first part (`:role = ''`) should be true so I would expect to get *ALL* data.
But for some reason it doesn't work in this particular case.

*ProductRepository.java*:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "/product")
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    @RestResource(path="filter", rel="filter")
    @Query("select p from Product p where"
        + "(:vendor = '' or lower(p.vendor.name) like concat('%', lower(:vendor), '%'))"
        + "and"
        + "(:role = '' or lower(p.role.name) like concat('%', lower(:role), '%'))"
    Page<Product> filterProduct(@Param("role") String role, Pageable pageable);
}
```

*Product.java*:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Vendor vendor;
}
```

*Role.java*:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

*Vendor.java*:

```
@Entity
public class Vendor {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
```

**My Tests**

For testing I replaced the second part of the expression with a statement that is always true or false (`1=1` or `1=2`).

*ProductRepository.java*:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "/product")
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    @RestResource(path="filter", rel="filter")
    @Query("select p from Product p where"
        + "(:role = '' or 1=2)"
    Page<Product> filterProduct(@Param("role") String role, Pageable pageable);
}
```

*Case `1=1`*:

It doesn't matter if I provide the `role` parameter or not, I always get *ALL* products.

*Case `1=2`*:

If I do not provide the `role` parameter (e.g. `http://localhost/product/search/filter?role=`) I get *ALL* products because `:role = ''` evaluates to `true`.

If I do provide the `role` parameter (e.g. `http://localhost/product/search/filter?role=foo`) I get an empty set because no role with the name 'foo' exists.

I thought that maybe because `p.role` is null trying to match `p.role.name` results in an error, but there is no error message and I also tried to include `p.role is not null and ...` in the expression but with no change.

**Summary**:

- `:role = ''` alone works as expected.
- `:role = ''` combined with a simple expression works.
- `:role = ''` combined with the expression I want does **not** work.

Comment: `p.role.name` is an implicit inner join. Just look at the generated SQL. You should just use another method if you don't have any role.

Comment: I added another parameter `vendor` which currently is never `null`. The implicit inner join works just fine in that case, e.g. `?vendor=foo` results in products from vendor 'foo' only. What exactly do you mean with 'another method'?

Comment: `Page<Product> findAllProducts(Pageable pageable)`.

Comment: And have you looked at "the generated SQL"? because that ought to be step 1 in debugging problematic queries

Comment: @JBNizet: That method works of course, but I require server side filtering.

Comment: @NeilStockton: I have, but I guess I wasn't paying attention to the right parts. Somehow I missed the implicit inner join, which is done in a sub query. So the question remains: how can I achieve combined filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly access associated entity columns using dot notation. Declare the join with alias to access:

```
@RestResource(path="filter", rel="filter")
@Query("select p from Product p LEFT JOIN p.role r LEFT JOIN p.vendor v where"
    + "(:vendor = '' or lower(v.name) like concat('%', lower(:vendor), '%'))"
    + "and"
    + "(:role = '' or lower(r.name) like concat('%', lower(:role), '%'))")
Page<Product> filterProduct(@Param("vendor") String vendor, @Param("role") String role);
```